# Image sizing via CSS doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have style like this:

```
input.date_picker, input.datetime_picker {
    background-image: url("/images/calendar.png");
    background-size: 16px 16px;
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My datepicker inputs have this small calendar positioned to right and sized 16x16. In IE8 it doesn't work and image takes whole background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background-size for IE is only supported in IE9+. The best thing to do is to re-size the image in an image editor first to the correct size and then re-upload it. That way you are not relying on CSS3 background-size browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Background Size property is a CSS3 property and it is not supported by Internet Explorer 8. You can try putting the image as a image-sprite, not a background sprite with positioning and try. Or you can make IE 8 background sizing to work this way:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```